# Hiding content using JS while displaying a loading gif for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript

The code I've got so far is:

```
var content = document.getElementById("show-deed");
content.style.display="none";

setTimeout(function(){
content.style.display="block";
}, 11000);

if (content.style.display == 'none') {
content.style.backgroundImage = "url('{{asset('/icons/black/upload-icon.svg')}}')";
           };
```

The first half of the code is working in the sense it's hiding the content for the set 11 seconds,
although whilst that's happening I want to be able to display a seperate loading gif image only for those 11 seconds.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

also I'm using laravel/ blade syntax to set the backgroundImage

Comment: You can use [spin.js](http://spin.js.org) for the gif, just plain css hiding and showing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. Although the code I have hides/shows  already But I need to remove the content of the Div whilst replacing it with the gif, after the timeout then remove the gif and display the contents of the div.

I'm not sure if plan css hiding/showing would achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here (line with "//") :

```
if (content.style.display == 'none') {
    // This makes no sense as you are setting an background image to an invisible div
    content.style.backgroundImage = "url('{{asset('/icons/black/upload-icon.svg')}}')";
};
```

I would suggest you create another div with the background image by default visible and after 11 seconds you hide that div and show the other div

```
var content = document.getElementById("show-deed");
var bgdiv = document.getElementById("image");
content.style.display="none";

setTimeout(function(){
    bgdiv.style.display="none";
    content.style.display="block";
}, 11000);
```

Comment: I've accepted & upvoted you're answer although it's not publicly visible because I don't have enough reputation points :(

Comment: No problem. Glad to help ;)